# Geting textbox value in msgbox excel VBA

Tags: excel, textbox, msgbox, vba

I want a message box to appear after someone has entered a wrong value For example:

```
Msgbox("The value ""txtID"" is wrong")
```

So if i typed the wrong value the message box should say "The value 200(for example) is wrong" . How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Anything within double quotes will be considered as a string. Try this.

```
Msgbox("The value " & txtID & " is wrong")
```